# Как выбрать значения из всех столбцов кроме нескольких?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица, из которой надо выбрать значения из всех столбцов кроме нескольких, при этом имена нужных столбцов заранее не известны. Как построить такой запрос?

**Обновление**

```
CREATE TABLE session
(
  time timestamp without time zone,
  profit real,
  89932253 real,
  89946462 real,
  89949736 real
);
```

Имена столбцов генерируются, и нужно сделать выборку из всех столбцов кроме profit и time.

Comment: можете с структурой таблицы показать. Так как есть другие методы этого реализации через вторичную таблицу.

Comment: А как они становятся известны?

Comment: Чисто из спортивного интереса, зачем нужно исключать значения двух столбцов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список столбцов моно получить следующим запросом:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'session' AND column_name NOT IN ('time', 'profit')
```

Для финального запроса потребуется либо конкатенация с помощью plpgsql, либо конкатенация на уровне приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на уровне приложения запросил схему, а потом сконструировал запрос.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?